# Regex capture string up to character or end of line

Tags: regex

I need one regex to capture a string up to a `:`, but the problem is that the `:` is not always there.

At this moment I am able to capture the groups when I have the `:` but not when I dont.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**strings to capture**

```
XXX 1 A:B (working)

XXX 1 A: (working)

XXX A (not working)
```

My regex:
`^(?P<grp1>[A-Z]{3,10})\s(?P<grp2>.*)(?=\:)(?:.)*$`

Comment: Maybe just `^[^\n:]+`

Comment: @Eraklon I need the groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?P<grp1>[A-Z]{3,10})\s(?P<grp2>.*?)(?::.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ff02Zp/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<grp1>[A-Z]{3,10})` - Group "grp1": three to ten uppercase letters
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?P<grp2>.*?)` - Group "grp2": any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?::.*)?` - an optional group matching any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$`- end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally match a single `:` after it

```
^(?P<grp1>[A-Z]{3,10})\s(?P<grp2>[^:\r\n]*)(?::[^:\r\n]*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<grp1>[A-Z]{3,10})` Group `grp1`
- `\s` Match a whitspace char
- `(?P<grp2>[^:\r\n]*)` Group 2 `grp2` Match any char except `:` or a newline
- `(?::[^:\r\n]*)?` Optionally match a single `:` between optional chars other than `:` or a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lwc0fm/1)